# Magento send 1 year old order emails

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

i have a glitch in my magento 1.7. When 2017 come my customers start receive 2 order emails when place order(1 is correct but 2 is one year old). Maybe need to clean email queue ? if so, how ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are creating some scripts for the sales order. While an order is completed then the script is also synced with last order and it affects the order email system.